# Convert a column within a large dataset from UTC to PST in R

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I have a large dataset, df, that I would like to convert the Date column to PST. It is currently in UTC time.

```
   Date                        ID

   1/7/2020 1:35:08 AM         A
```

I would like to convert the Date column from UTC to PST, while preserving the other columns.

```
   Date                        ID

   1/7/2020 5:35:08 PM         A
```

Here is the dput:

```
  structure(list(Date = structure(1L, .Label = "1/7/2020 1:35:08 AM", class = "factor"), 
  ID = structure(1L, .Label = "A", class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -1L))
```

This is what I have tried:

```
  library(lubridate)
  newdata <- as.POSIXct(Sys.Date())
```

However, I am unsure if I need to add format and what other code needs to be added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `lubridate` you can do :

```
library(lubridate)
df$Date <- mdy_hms(df$Date)
df$Date <- with_tz(df$Date, tzone = "America/Los_Angeles")
df

#                 Date ID
#1 2020-01-06 17:35:08  A
```

Or in base R :

```
df$Date <- as.POSIXct(df$Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p", tz = "UTC")
attributes(df$Date)$tzone <- "America/Los_Angeles"
```

Comment: Ok let me try, and how would I further change from the military time of 17:38 to 5:38? thank you

Comment: You can use `format` to get output in desired format as shown `df$Date <- format(df$Date, "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")`